# CIFS component to wrap around given CRUD web services

Tags: web-services, wrapper, adapter, cifs

I'm pretty sure this is a very particular request, and am slightly proud of it :-)

I am looking for a CIFS (Common Internet File System) adapter/layer/wrapper around an existing set of web services, that takes an incoming CIFS request and translates it to some calls to these web services.

Explanation:

Say we have a document management system that **provides nice web services to "crudl" (create/read/update/delete/list) files and directories**.

Say that this document management system **does *not* support the CIFS protocol**, which is the protocol that enables users to open a directory from that system in Windows Explorer as if it was a local folder.

Say that our users still want this feature. Wouldn't it be nice if we could simply install some kind of adapter **component which implements the CIFS protocol suite and, behind the scenes, calls to the given web services to perform the CRUD operations?** Of course it would need to be configured such that it knows where the services are and how to use them.

Do you know whether such a component exists? I didn't find any on google.

Or, if it does not exist, would it be difficult to implement one on my own (in C#, e.g.), or to take some existing CIFS implementation code and modify it?